# Connecting to topics using Rest proxy

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-rest

I am new to Kafka .I have implemented my consumer as normal Java springboot application.I need to connect to the topic deployed on remote broker using **Kafka rest proxy**.
I am not able to understand how it will function differently if i use Kafka rest proxy.Where i should do change in my code to include the rest proxy.Do i need to structure my code complete different as i didn't think about rest proxy while creation.
I maybe wrong with the terminologies.
Any help or guidance would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST proxy would be used with any HTTP client, not a Kafka consumer (so create a WebClient bean rather than a ConsumerFactory, etc)

You can refer its documentation for how you can consume records over HTTP, but, simply put, the code will be completely different up until you parse the data